# iPhone sdk - Get date from NSFileCreationDate

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I get the created date and time of a file using `attributesOfItemAtPath:`. I get the `NSString` as result which displays `Date Created: 2011-08-23 10:47:33 +0000`. But, how can I retrieve the information about the date alone from the `NSString` ignoring the information about time. i.e. my result should be like `Date Created: 2011-08-23`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't the attributesOfItemAtPath: return an NSDate? That's what the docs says. To get a string with just the date from an NSDate, use an NSDateFormatter. Code might look a bit like this:

```
NSDictionary* attributesDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: path error: NULL];
NSDate* date = [attributesDictionary objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString* justDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'r actual getting back an `NSDate` not string:

```
NSString *filePathName = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePathName error:&error];

// No attributes then jst skip the file
if (!attributes || error) {
   NSLog(@"Error getting attributes for: %@\nWith error: %@", filePathName, error);
   retun;
}

NSDate *modifiedDate = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
```

With a `NSDateFormatter` you get the string from that date:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] 
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *datestring = [formatter stringFromDate:modifiedDate];
[formatter release], formatter = nil;
```